# Python: Tkinter file dialogues

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe, pyinstaller

I am using Tkinter and pyinstaller (python 2.7) and I can't seem to get file dialouges working

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
save_dir = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
```

When uncompiled it works fine but when compiled to exe it just freezes the script and does not open the dialogue. I have seen this issue cured for py2exe but not pyinstaller

Comment: ...What does this have to do with pygame or a "click and drag select area"?

Comment: Sorry, it took the title from my last post, how do I change it?

Comment: @stopmotionheaven you can click the edit link and make changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to import tkFileDialog

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
save_dir = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
```